# Dense subpace of ${C_0}\left( \Omega \right)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega  \subset {\mathbb{R}^n}$ is subset and bounded, $f \in C\left( {\bar \Omega } \right),{\left. f \right|_{\partial \Omega }} = 0$, can we find sequence $\left\{ {{f_n}} \right\} \subset C_c^\infty \left( \Omega  \right)$ such that ${\left\| {{f_n} - f} \right\|_{C\left( {\bar \Omega } \right)}} \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\Omega$ is open and connected, yes. All you have to do is approximate $f$ by  a sequence of polynomials and multiply them by a $C^{\infty}$ function which is 1 outside an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of the boundary with support inside $\Omega$. It may help to write $\Omega$ as  acountable union of compact sets $K_n$ such that $K_n \subset K_{n+1}^{0}$ and choose $C^{\infty}$ functions which are 1 on $K_n$ and 0 off $K_{n+1}$.